# Is there a way to loop a function for a separate input using data from an API in python?

Tags: python, arrays, json, rest, loops

I probably worded the title wrong. I am wondering if it's possible to repeat a function for a specific input. Showing the code would make it easier to explain.
Here is the code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json

def askbot(bus_stop):

    if bus_stop == "CU2":
        url = urlopen("https://transportapi.com/v3/uk/bus/stop/43001053801/live.json?app_id=&app_key=&group=route&nextbuses=yes")
        data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
        json_str=json.dumps(data)
        resp=json.loads(json_str)  
        which_line = input("Which bus line would you like to know? ")
        if which_line == "10":
           print("Here is the current expected departure time at bus stop " + bus_stop + " for bus line " + resp['departures']['10'][0]['line_name'] + " heading to " + resp['departures']['10'][0]['direction'])
           print("Expected departure time: " + resp['departures']['10'][0]['expected_departure_time'])
           print("The next bus at bus stop " + bus_stop + "," + " for bus line " + resp['departures']['10'][1]['line_name'] + " will be heading to " + resp['departures']['10'][1]['direction'])
        elif which_line == "8":
            print
        else:
            print("That is not a valid line!")
    else:
        print("That bus stop does not exist!")
which_stop = input("Which bus stop timetable would you like to know? ")

askbot(which_stop)
```

My question is, where it asks the user for `which_line`, is there a way to make the bot automatically search the inputted bus line's expected departure time without having to manually copy the code for each bus line? For example, if I input the bus line '8' for the bus stop 'CU2', the bot will check the API for that stop and find the bus line '8' and print the expected departure time.

I can provide more details if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something along those lines, assuming the index is similar to the way you did it above:

```
which_line = input("Which bus line would you like to know? ")

try:
    print("Here is the current expected departure time at bus stop " + bus_stop + " for bus line " +
        resp['departures'][which_line][0]['line_name'] + " heading to " + resp['departures'][which_line][0]['direction'])
    print("Expected departure time: " +
        resp['departures'][which_line][0]['expected_departure_time'])
    print("The next bus at bus stop " + bus_stop + "," + " for bus line " +
        resp['departures'][which_line][1]['line_name'] + " will be heading to " + resp['departures'][which_line][1]['direction'])
# If Line was not found
except KeyError as err:
    print("%s is not a valid line: %s" % (which_line, err))
```

This way you will not have to write if statements for all your lines, if you input something that isnt in your dict you should get a KeyError as the element cant be found, here we catch it and output your error alongside the input the user gave.

Instead of printing out the output I would also suggest to return the information you are looking for instead and then print it out in the main loop. This way your function is more reuseable. Also when catching the KeyError think about using **raise** (To return a custom error) or **return** as well instead of printing it out like I did here.

Comment: This worked and is much better than what I had done! Thank you. I will also take your advice and try returning it back to a main loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could just insert the line number as a variable.

```
which_line = input("Which bus line would you like to know? ")
print("Here is the current expected departure time at bus stop " + bus_stop + " for bus line " + resp['departures'][which_line][0]['line_name']
```

Notice that

```
resp['departures']['10'][0]['line_name']
```

becomes

```
resp['departures'][which_line][0]['line_name']
```

---

This will also depend on the API you are using. If it can accept a line number, you could make the API call after the user enters the line number and only retrieve the data for that line.

Comment: This worked but what would happen if there was only 1 bus line at the time? would it still print `print("The next bus at bus stop " + bus_stop + "," + " for bus line " + resp['departures'][which_line][1]['line_name'] + " will be heading to " + resp['departures'][which_line][1]['direction'])` or will an error occur. Also wouldn't I still have to create separate if statements for each bus line? Not that I would mind. Thanks again.

Comment: @BeginnerAtLife The way your code is structured, there will only be one bus line entered by the user at this point anyway. You won’t need an `if else` statement because the variable is being used directly as a key in the dictionary from the API.

Answer (score 0):

I'm inferring that the reason you didn't just reuse `which_line` is because you don't want to accept all values. If that's the case, I would suggest you create a list of acceptable values and make that be your condition.

```
existing_lines = [10, 8, 7, 12, 21]
if which_line in existing_lines:
    print("Here is the current expected departure time at bus stop " + bus_stop + " for bus line " + resp['departures'][which_line][0]['line_name']
```